Two polynomials $f$, $g$ over $\mathbb{C}$ define the same function iff they have the same coefficients
Two polynomials $f$, $g$ over $\mathbb{C}$ define the same function iff they have the same coefficients
The proof of this in my textbook is nonsensical to me, and extraordinarily frustrating. I reproduce it below in hope someone can decipher it for me. 
By taking the difference of the two polynomials, we must prove that if $f(t)\in\mathbb{C}[t]$ and $f(t)=0\space\forall t\in\mathbb{C}$, then the coefficients of $f$ are all $0$.
Let $P(n)$ be the statement: If a polynomial over $f(t)$ over $\mathbb{C}$  has degree $n$ and $f(t)=0$ for all $t\in\mathbb{C}$, then $f=0$. We prove $P(n)$ by induction on $n$. 
Both $P(0)$ and $P(1)$ are obvious. Suppose that $P(n-1)$ is true. Let $$f(t)=a_nt^n+...+a_0$$ and note $f(0)=0$ so that $a_0=0$. 
This last line of reasoning seems dead wrong to me. Can anyone explain it to me? Shouldn't $f(0)=a_0$ like normal?
The author continues by then noting because of above: $$f(t)=a_nt^n+...+a_1t$$ $$=t(a_nt^{n-1}+...+a_1)$$ $$=tg(t)$$
where $g(t)=a_nt^{n-1}+...+a_1$ has degree $n-1$. Now $g(t)$ vanishes for all $t\in\mathbb{C}$ except perhaps at $t=0$. However, if $g(0)=a_1\neq0$ then $g(t)\neq0$ for $t$ sufficiently small. Therefore $g(t)$ vanishes for all $t$. By induction $g=0$. Therefore $f=0$ so $P(n)$ is true. 

Yes, $f(0)=a_0$, but isn't $f$ assumed to be $0$ for all $t\in\mathbb{C}$ ?

That's what I was thinking he meant, but he explicitly says we're assuming $P(n-1)$ is true i.e. $g(t)=b_{n-1}t^{n-1}+...+b_0$ has coefficients all $0$ since $g(t)=0$ for all $t$.

In fact, the statement is true for polynomials over any infinite field or integral domain.

$(f-g)(x)=f(x)-g(x)=0x^n+0x^{n-1}+\cdots 0x+0=0$ for all $x$. Thus $f=g$.

$f(t) = 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{C}$ so in particular $f(0) = 0$. Since $a_0 = f(0)$ it follows that $a_0 = 0$.
This is an instance of the factor theorem. If $f(\alpha) = 0$ then $f$ is divisible by $t - \alpha$. So the fact that $f(\alpha) = 0$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ means that $f$ is divisible by $t - \alpha$ for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$.
So we can say for example, that $f(t) = tg_1(t)$ since $f$ is divisible by $t$ and then we can say that $0 = f(1) = 1g_1(1)$ so $g_1$ is divisble by $t - 1$. So $f(t) = t(t-1)g_2(t)$ and then $f(t) = t(t-1)(t-2)g_3(t)$ and so on. You don't need to use $0,1,2,\dots$ as your roots either. And the point of all this is that if $f$ is not the zero polynomial then it has infinite degree, which is impossible.
